# Get innerwidth of transformed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What I want is to get the actual width of an element that is in a transformed container.

in the example bellow, innerWidth give 150 px whereas the actual width is 75px (and that is the value that I need)

how to get the actual width?

```js
let w = $("#child").innerWidth()
console.info(w);
```

```css
#parent {
position:relative;
transform:scale(0.5)
}

#child {
width:150px;
height:150px;
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
<div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879650/get-width-and-height-of-image-after-scaling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the native element function `getBoundingClientRect()` to extract an object containing the original viewport information (position, size, etc). Use `[0]` from the JQuery object to retrieve the native DOM element.

```js
let w = $("#child")[0].getBoundingClientRect()

console.info(w);

console.info(w.width + "x" + w.height);
```

```css
#parent {
position:relative;
transform:scale(0.5)
}

#child {
width:150px;
height:150px;
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
<div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get width which will be `75`

Run snippet below.

```js
let w = $('#child')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
console.log(w);
```

```css
#parent {
position:relative;
transform:scale(0.5)
}

#child {
width:150px;
height:150px;
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
<div id="child"></div>
</div>
```